# How to pass the host name,username and password through command line arguments in junit?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jar, command-line-arguments

I don't want to use system.getproperty or setproperty.I have a before method which fetches a URL

```
@Before
public void setUp( String baseUrl){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
}

@test
public void logIn(){ 
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xxx");
}
```

When I call the above Junit test case through:

```
D:\>java -cp D:\Jars\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar;D:\Jars\junit-4.11.jar;D:\Jars\POC_PR
OJECT.jar;D:\Jars\selenium-java-2.31.0.jar;D:\Jars\selenium-server-standalone-2.
31.0.jar **-Dbaseurl="https://gmail.com/"** org.junit.runner.JUnitCore POC.LogInTest
```

**The browser opens but no URL is opened and fails by saying 1) `logIn(POC.LogInTest)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null..`
I tried writing the URL in `@test` also,but no use.**

Could somebody tell me how the command line will know in junit on how the -DbaseUrl should get linked to baseUrl mentioned in `@test` or `@before`..
**In simple words how to pass the url value to the junit code through cmd line.**

Thx a ton in advance..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't link baseUrl parameter with parameter passed in command line via the framework itself.

The thing you can do is to write custom AOP which will intercept the call of `setUp(String baseUrl)` read `baseUrl` via `System.getProperty("baseUrl")` and pass it to method as parameter. But is it worth it?